# How to append Cart Item in local Storage, Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage, shopping-cart

I want to add products in cart using localStorage in cart.
How can I save Items and append them yo cart list.
I am able to show items if cart is in home page but If I want to appear items added to other pages or cart.html (separate page) I need localStorage. I dont know how to storage these dynamic list items in localStorage.

Cart.html

```
 <div id="cart">
      <div class="divider-header">
      <p class="cart-heading"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"><span class="badge shopping-bag-badge">0</span></i>Your Cart</p>
      <a href="#" class="closebtn closecart">
      <div><span id="first"></span><span id="second"></span></div></a>
      </div>
      <div id="empty-cart">
        <img src="images/empty-cart.png" alt="">
        <h3>Your Cart is Empty!</h3>
        <small>Looks like you haven't added anything to your cart yet</small>
        <a href="#">Continue Shopping</a>
      </div>

      <!--Cart List-->
        <ul id="cartList">
        </ul>
        <p id="shipping_text">Shipping Cost : $2</p>
        <p id="total_amount_text">Total Amount : <span></span></p>
        <a type="button" id="checkout">Check Out</a>
        <a type="button" id="clear-cart">Clear Cart</a>
   </div>
```

//Items in home page

```
 <div><img class="skincare-soapimg" src="images/skincaresoap4.png" alt=""></div>
              <p class="skincare-soapname">Skin Paradise</p>
              <p class="skincare-soapprice">$23</p>
              <a class="slider-btn addToCart" type="button" data-id="4" data-image="images/skincaresoap4.png" 
              data-price="$23" data-name="Skin Paradise" data-quantity="1" data-weight="150g" data-availability="In Stock">SHOP NOW</a>
            </div>
```

Jquery code
$(".addToCart").click(function(){

```
    // animate button
    var total = 0;
    var shipping = 2;
    var flag = 0;

    //check if cart is empty to remove empty cart view
           if( ($("#cartList").has("li").length === 0) ) { 
            $("#empty-cart").css("display","none");}
           
    //Get all data of item to be added
        var id= $(this).data("id");
        var price= $(this).data("price");
        var image = $(this).data('image');
        var name = $(this).data("name");
        var quantity = $(this).data("quantity");
        var availability = $(this).data("availability");
        var weight = $(this).data("weight");

    //Traverse the cart list to check if item already exists or not
        $( "#cartList li" ).each(function( index) {
            var matched = $( this ).find(".id").text();
             if (matched == id){
             var increment= $( this ).find(".quantity").val();
              increment++;
              flag = 1;
              $( this ).find(".quantity").val(increment);
                return false;
               }
           });

      //Add new Item in cart
          if(flag == 0){
            var cartItem= $("<li class='newItem'> <p class='id'>"+id+"</p><div class='picture'><img src='"+ image +"' ></div> <div class='details'><p class='name'>"+name+"</p><span class='weight'>"+weight+"</span><span> /</span> <span class='avail'>"+availability+"</span> <p class='price'>"+price+"</p><a type='button' class='inc'>+</a><input type='text' class='quantity' pattern='[0-9]+' value="+quantity+" ><a type='button' class='dec'>-</a></div> <a type='button' class='removeItem'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></li>");

               //increment in badge icon number when new item added in cart
                 
                  var counterInc = parseInt($(".badge").html()) + 1;
                    $(".badge").html(counterInc);
             }
```

})

Comment: Hi, the problem here seems to be that there's no separation of UI with the domain logic. If you had a cart list, you could simply store that cart in the localStorage - and reuse the same cart in performing UI operations. For a basic check like to see if the cart is empty, you have to traverse the UI layer using Jquery - this should not be the case. The cart being empty or not is not a concern for UI and there should be no jquery on it. I would prefer making this separation first - and the rest should become trivial. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any references to `localStorage` in your example code. Putting that aside. `window.localStorage` is a simple key+value data storage. Read [more about localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

One way to address data storage in `localStorage` is to serialize an `object` or `array` into JSON and store the string produced as the value for a key. Here is some pseudo code for a function that takes an object and adds to an array in localStorage.

It first gets the value from `localStorage` for the key `cart` then deserializes the value from a string to array.  Next, it pushes the new item onto the array. The process is reversed and the newly updated array is serialized as JSON to a string and is set for the key `cart` . We leverage the methods `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` to handle deserialization/serialization.

```
/**
  @param {object} cartItem - {name,price,id}
*/

function addToCart(cartItem) {
  const existing = localStorage.getItem('cart');
  const shoppingCart = [];
  if(existing) {
    try {
     shoppingCart.push(...JSON.parse(existing))
    } catch(err) { console.error('ERROR deserializing cart',err); }
  }
  shoppingCart.push(cartItem);
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(shoppingCart));
}
/**
  @param {array} shoppingCart - collection (array of objects)
  [{name,price,id},{name,price,id}...]
*/
function replaceCart(shoppingCart) {
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(shoppingCart));
}
// append item foo with price 1000 to existing cart
addToCart({name:'foo', price:1000, id:'abcFoo'})
```

That said, by the looks of your code `//Traverse the cart list to check if item already exists or not` comment appears to be a place where you could add items to an array, then just replace the entire value in the cart. I provided an additional function called `replaceCart`, which takes an array and overwrites all existing values. The implementation of whether you are appending or replacing would depend on a variety of other factors outside the scope of this question.

Probably worth noting: there are many drawbacks using `localStorage` for a shopping cart. For instance, since `localStorage` is local and not a remote server, when users move from mobile to desktop their shopping cart is local to that device. Additionally, Safari web browser places a [7 day cap on script-writeable storage](https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/#:%7E:text=Service%20Worker%20registrations%20and%20cache).

`localStorage` can be useful as a way to handle data between tabs/views. There is also a `StorageEvent` that fires whenever a change is made to the storage object. This can be useful when working with `localStorage` across multiple tabs. [Read more about using storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: I understand, I made an array of objects